# Syncing development environment between OSX and Windows

Tags: synchronization, development-environment

I currently have a portable XAMPP server on a USB flash drive so I can develop on either my desktop or my laptop.

However, recently I bought a mac laptop, but I'm still using Windows on the desktop. Now I can't use the USB flash drive trick to code anywhere.

What method would you suggest to have two local development environments (on laptop and desktop) that are both synced (even databases, server settings..etc)?

I'd like to be able to work locally not remotely, since many times I have to work in a place where I don't have an internet connection.

Your input is much appreciated

Comment: any reason you're not using version control?

Comment: Version control shouldn't be used for file sync.  If the code is not ready then it should not be checked in to the version control system, but he might need to work on that file on the other machine.

Comment: Agreed if it's not ready it shouldn't be checked into a central repository, but you can always use a distributed version control system like git and just check into local and checkout from there. When something is production ready check into the central repo.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at SyncMate: http://www.sync-mac.com/